# Android trigger onTouch after onLongPress

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, gesturedetector

I am currently trying to implement Drag and Drop in Android. The draging should be done on an item from a ListView. The thing is that the elements(items) in this ListView should have some sort of action when they are touched (single taped) and they should be dragable after the user perform a long press on one of the items. I got the code for draging from a tutorial but the problem that i cannot solve is:
After the user holds his finger on an item from the ListView the onTouch(MotionEvent ev) is called at the beginning and after a second GestureDetector.onLongPress is called.
My draging logic is implemented in the onTouch methods. What i currently do is set a boolean (isLongPressed) to true after LongPress is enabled and in the onTouch methods i check if this boolean is true - if yes then perform the draging.

Here is my code :

```
    public class DragNDropListView extends ListView implements  GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener
    {

    private boolean isLongPressed

    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    if (!isLongPressed)
    {
        Log.e("Not Long", "Its Not Longpressed yet");
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final int x = (int) ev.getX();
    final int y = (int) ev.getY();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && isLongPressed)
    {
        mDragMode = true;
    }

    if (!mDragMode)
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);

    switch (action)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    Log.e("Action down", "Down");
    break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.e("ACTION MOVE", "Move");
            drag()
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            isLongPressed = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent ev)
{
    Log.e("LongPress", "LongPressed");
    isLongPressed = true;
    mGestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(isLongPressed);
    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

What happens is that i get "isNotLongPressed" if i just tab the items (desired behavior), After a long press i get "LongPressed" but then if i start draging i get nothing. If i release my finger and then start the drag everything is ok but i want to be able to drag immediately after the long press is registered.

Comment: What i did to fix my problem was that i added the startDrag and drag methods in onLonpress. Because the onLongPress has a MotionEvent as an argument i can use it to get the X and Y so i called my drag method there.